# Try Login HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse c# WPF

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to login this site: http://svp.correios.com.br/core/seguranca/entrar.php

But in the end, he still does not login, I am opening the page, capturing the session and trying to login, why in the end, dont work login?

look my code:

```
string url = "http://svp.correios.com.br/core/seguranca/entrar.php";
        //request page to login
        HttpWebRequest request01 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request01.CookieContainer = _cookies;
        request01.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //load page
        HttpWebResponse return01 = (HttpWebResponse)request01.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = return01.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));


        //get section
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        String[] rastreamentoCompleto = Regex.Split(responseFromServer, "<section id=\"geral\">\n\t<form id=\"fm1\" action=\"");
        String[] retiraFim = Regex.Split(rastreamentoCompleto[1], "\" method=\"post\">\n    <div id");
        string keySection = retiraFim[0];

        //try login
        HttpWebRequest request02 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://apps.correios.com.br" + keySection);
        request02.CookieContainer = _cookies;
        request02.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "username="+ user + "&password="+ password;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request02.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request02.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        dataStream = request02.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();




        //check if Logged
        HttpWebResponse return02 = (HttpWebResponse)request02.GetResponse();
        dataStream = return02.GetResponseStream();
        reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: You have to parse all the `<INPUT>` elements (that page has hidden `<INPUT>` elements; those need to be posted URL-Encoded along with the others). It doesn't have a `__VIEWSTATE` (but it could, so you should parse for that, too). If the UserName or Password fields contain an email address, don't URL-Encode that field.

Comment: how can I do that?